# Form not working when it's inside of a 'section'

Tags: html, angular, frontend

So I'm building the portfolio with Angular dividing the different parts with *sections*.

The contact section looks like this:

```
<section>
  <form class="mat-elevation-z4 p-5" (click)="sendMessage()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="name"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="email"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Write your message here" class="message"/>
    <button>Click</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

When the form is wrapped in the section, the inputs act like they're *readonly*. If I remove the section tag, it works perfectly.

How can I do it so that the form is wrapped in the section tag?

Comment: I am unable to recreate the problem in plain HTML. Are you using some sort of framework that is parsing this code (*if so, please include a tag*)?

Comment: Yep. I'm using AngularJS, working in the app.component.html. I'll add it to the question!

Comment: AngularJS isn't Angular. Please tag appropriately and revise your post to be clear about which you're using.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that! I meant Angular